# From the 'find grants' report, I wish to bulk 'upgrade' all chosen but want to put in the date money transferred

Tags: grant

I wish to put in the date money transferred in my upgrade grants.  Currently only have the option to put in Grant decision.  Want to add the additional line - Money transferred.  How do I do this?[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are only few fields available on the update all grants actions. If a new field needs to added you can add via extension using buildform hook.

But there is an [extension that does bulk update on grant](https://civicrm.org/extensions/batch-update-grants-profile). This extension uses Civi profile, this allows you to add fields in a profile to be available on bulk update screen.

Answer (score 2):

Besides Pradeep's answer, SearchKit should do what you need.

- go to **Search menu » SearchKit**.
- Select **New Search**.
- In *Search for*, select **Grants**.
- Add some columns with the "Add" button so you can identify which grants you'd be editing (see screenshot, item 1).
- Press **Search** to confirm (item 2).
- Once you're satisfied you can distinguish which grants are which, add some filters in the **Where** section (item 3) and press **Search** again.
- When you're happy with your list, either a) check the boxes next to individual grants, or b) click the checkbox selector under **Search** to select all.
- Click the **Actions** button (item 4) and select **Update Grants**.

You can now choose "Money Transferred", or any other grant field, with a value to set in all selected grants.

[image: SearchKit showing the UI for editing grants]